# Passing a user-entered input value to another php page

Tags: php, html, string, input, get

I have an input box in index.php which takes some user input and queries a database using that input field as an attribute. This input is stored in $arrInput[0].

I also have a link to inspect.php which, when clicked, takes me to inspect.php but I need to pass $resultArr[0] to inspect.php so that I can use that variable to continue doing other things within inspect.php. How can I achieve this? \

Currently this is what I have:

```
/* inspect.php  */
// Create a table with some rows. Then create this 
// column which has the inspect link
echo "<td>  <a href='inspect.php?id=<?php echo $resultArr[0]; ?>'>Inspect</a>
              </td>";
...
```

But I don't know how to access $resultArr[0] within inspect.php. I was told $_GET[] would help, but I'm not sure how and googling the subject hasn't been much help.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td><a href='inspect.php?id=".$resultArr[0]."'>Inspect</a></td>";
```

I think you are using wrong syntax. Please check above code. You can the access 'id' key inside $_GET.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

Not that hard. use `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: ah, dang faster than me, nice

Comment: I've been trying this but for some reason I can't display its value. This is what I have at the very top of inspect.php:
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '') {
    echo $_GET['id'];
    echo "yeah"
  
}
only "yeah" is getting displayed